# CPLEX with student edition on google colab

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-colaboratory, cplex, docplex

I have google colab but I get the warning for using CPLEX and Docplex :

```
9 frames
CplexSolverError: CPLEX Error  1016: Community Edition. Problem size limits exceeded. Purchase at http://ibm.biz/error1016.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

DOcplexLimitsExceeded                     Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/docplex/mp/error_handler.py in fatal_limits_exceeded(self)
    212     def fatal_limits_exceeded(self):
    213         docplex_error_stop_here()
--> 214         raise DOcplexLimitsExceeded()
    215 
    216 

DOcplexLimitsExceeded: **** Promotional version. Problem size limits exceeded, CPLEX code=1016
```

I want to use Google colab and I have the student version license already for CPLEX. How can I link my google colab with this? Do I need to be running to local run time?

Can someone show the steps to linking google colab to the student license CPLEX I have on my PC?

Thanks!

Comment: I have python 3.8.10 also and the cplex version I have is CPLEX 12.10.0

Answer (score 0):

The version of CPLEX that you can get through `pip install cplex` or `pip install docplex` (or anything similar) is the (free) Community Edition that's limited in the size of problems that you can solve. That's why you see this error.

The full version of CPLEX to which you have access through the Academic Initiative program is a *different* software.  It's different in the sense that the binary program is a different one: it's been compiled with different flags to not have the limitation of the Community Edition.

Google Colab being hosted by Google themselves, I don't see how you can configure it differently than it is. So I'm afraid that you can't use your Academic Initiative CPLEX version in Google Colab.

If you purchased instead a CPLEX subscription, I suppose that you could set up the corresponding key in Google Colab. But it's not free...

Comment: What if I run it as a local machine as a jupyter notebook?